# checking shutdown, login history

Tags: login

I used a raspberry pi with Raspbian installed. This board was used for a long experiment, and I want to record all logs. Then on a different PC, what could I do to check the histories?

Comment: The title suggests you want to record logins, but the question suggests you want to record the logs.  Which is it please?

Comment: Depending on what "long" is and what logs your after, I would just adjust the logrotate conf files to not delete any.  This way the older ones are still getting compressed, but you will retain all of them.   Then if still need to offload some of them you could have a periodic cron job that moves any *.tar files from /var/log to an external thumb drive( or another computer)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague, as to which logs you want, but most are in `/var/log` and old logs are rolled over (for varying periods - which is configurable) .

Below is a script I use to list apt-get history. You could adapt this to list any logs you are interested in.

This could be run remotely with changed paths; I usually run it over `ssh`

```
#!/bin/bash
#Print apt-get history
# 2017-08-06
for logf in $(ls /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz | sort -rV) ; do zcat $logf | grep -E "Start-Date:|Commandline:" ; done
# Include most recent
grep -E "Start-Date:|Commandline:" /var/log/apt/history.log
```

`dmesg -T` lists the kernel log, although this only shows recent entries.

`last -x` shows system shutdown entries